# Is my array the cause of rapid cpu & memory build up?

Tags: c++, ram, genetic-algorithm

My MCVC is compiling but is not functioning as intended. The goal is a genetic algorithm that performs the basics i.e. crossover,mutation,evolution. In the code I have provided should print out the good job statements but thats not the case. I am a new programmer, sorry.
My questions are:

1) The cpu and ram are rev'ed up, is this array declaration and implementation the cause for the uncontrolled spike?

```
std::array<std::auto_ptr<Individual>,50>myarray;
```

2) Is my 2.53 GHz Intel Core 2 Duo not up for it?

3) Should I cut down the amount of loops?

Any help is always welcomed !

Individual.h

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <vector>
#include <array>
#include <iostream>
class Individual
{
public:

    inline int getRandomNumber(int min = 0, int max = 1)
    {
        srand(static_cast<unsigned int>(time(0)));
        static const double fraction = 1.0 / (static_cast<double>(RAND_MAX) + 1.0);
        return static_cast<int>(rand() * fraction * (max - min + 1) + min);
    }
private:
    int defaultGeneLength = 64;
    std::vector<char>genes;
    int fitness = 0;

public:
    Individual()
    {
        std::cout<<"Good Job";

    }

    //setters and getters
    void generateIndividual();
    void setDefaultGeneLength(int length);
    char getGene(int index);
    void setGene(int index, char value);

    //public methods
    unsigned int size();
    int getFitness();
    std::string toString();
};
```

Individual.cpp

```
#include "Individual.h"

void Individual::generateIndividual()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size(); i++)
    {
        genes.push_back(getRandomNumber());
    }
}


//setters and getters
void Individual::setDefaultGeneLength(int length)
{
    defaultGeneLength = length;
}


char Individual::getGene(int index)
{
    return genes.at(index);

}


void Individual::setGene(int index, char value)
{
    genes[index] = value;
    fitness = 0;
}


//public methods
unsigned int Individual::size()
{
    return genes.max_size();
}


int Individual::getFitness()
{
    if(fitness == 0)
    {
        fitness = 1;

    }   return fitness;

}


std::string Individual::toString()
{
    std::string geneString = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < size(); i++)
    {
        geneString.append(getGene(i),1);
    }
    return geneString;

}
```

Population.h

```
#include "Individual.h"

class Population
{
std::array<std::auto_ptr<Individual>,50>myarray;

public:


    Population(int populationSize, bool initialise)
    {
        std::cout<<"Good Job2";
        if(initialise)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < populationSize; ++i)
            {
                std::auto_ptr<Individual>newIndividual(new Individual());
                myarray.at(i) = newIndividual;
                myarray.at(i)->generateIndividual();
                saveIndividual(i,*(myarray.at(i)));
            }
        }
        std::cout<<"Good Job 3";
    }

    Individual getIndividual(int index);
    Individual getFittest();
    unsigned long size();
    void saveIndividual (int index, Individual indiv);

    ~Population()
    {

    }
};
```

Population.cpp

```
#include "Population.h"
Individual Population::getIndividual(int index)
{
    return *myarray.at(index);
}

Individual Population::getFittest()
{
    Individual fittest = *myarray.at(0);

    for (int i = 0; i < myarray.max_size(); i++)
    {
        if (fittest.getFitness() <= getIndividual(i).getFitness())
        {
            fittest = getIndividual(i);
        }
    }
    return fittest;
}

unsigned long Population::size()
{
    return myarray.max_size();
}

void Population::saveIndividual (int index, Individual indiv)
{
    *myarray.at(index) = indiv;
}
```

Main.cpp

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    Population *mypop = new Population(2,true);
    delete mypop;
    mypop = nullptr;
return 0;
}
```

Comment: A general comment: do NOT use `auto_ptr` anymore, use `unique_ptr` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
unsigned int Individual::size()
{
    return genes.max_size();
}
```

Your `genes` is a:

```
std::vector<char> genes;
```

The C++ standard defines `std::vector::max_size()` as follows:

> distance(begin(), end()) for the largest possible container

It is not specified what "largest possible container" means. "Possible" could mean anything, like, if the system had a ten terabyte hard drive, so that the operating system could use the entire hard drive to page its virtual memory address space. That's certainly "possible", in some sense of the word. But it goes without saying that paging out ten terabytes will take a while.

With 64 bit gcc, the following simple program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<char> c;

    std::cout << c.max_size() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Produces the following output:

```
18446744073709551615
```

However, my chances of being able to actually create a vector of such size are not very good.

But let's get back to your code:

```
void Individual::generateIndividual()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size(); i++)
    {
        genes.push_back(getRandomNumber());
    }
}
```

Ok. You must be feeling quite lucky. You believe that it will be possible for you to create a `vector<char>` that's `max_size()` big.

Are you quite sure about that?

I'm somewhat skeptical.

Comment: :) Fortunately, his code will limit itself to 2^32 (by the use of `unsigned`) - only 4GB of genes per individual - super-humans most probable, as the number of *base pairs* (building blocks for genes) in the human genome is  about 3G. Unfortunately, he's trying to evolve a 4G population of them (he used the same technique and data type in the `Population` class). I'd be worried if he'd have any chances to succeed.